# What to do with unloved questions?

Tags: discussion

There are a few questions that I am not sure exactly what to think of:

- [How can one make Tor faster, when willing to to sacrifice anonymity?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/217/how-can-one-make-tor-faster-when-willing-to-to-sacrifice-anonymity)
- [What events led to Freedom Hosting going down?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/173/what-events-led-to-freedom-hosting-going-down)
- [Would distributed denial of service (DDoS) attacks on the directory authorities disrupt the Tor network?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/196/would-distributed-denial-of-service-ddos-attacks-on-the-directory-authorities)

and it seems I'm not the only one who's at best ambivalent about them.

In particular, the first doesn't seem like something we should encourage or help with, the second one has been discussed in [Is this question about the disappearence of Freedom Hosting on topic?](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/is-this-question-about-the-disappearence-of-freedom-hosting-on-topic) already.  The answer to the third seems obvious, but giving a thorough answer would probably mean providing a how-to on how to bring down the network.

Are these (or at least #1 and #3) instances where I should vote to close the question?

Comment: By chance I asked "the first doesn't seem like something we should encourage or help with". Can you please elaborate why there should be no help with that question?

Comment: @adrelanos, it seems to me that #1 is either asking "how do I abuse Tor to be my single hop proxy" or "how do I take more than my fair share"

Comment: I can accept that. For me, it's non-obvious that this is an inappropriate question. And I apologize for asking. If that is what the maintainers of the network think, and you certainly know more about that than I do, I propose not allowing such questions in some kind of forum rules.

Answer (score 4):

- Would distributed denial of service (DDoS) attacks on the directory authorities disrupt the Tor network?

I find that is an interesting question. It's about the limits of the Tor network. Weaknesses in Tor have never been tried to keep secret. I'd like to know the answer to that question. Don't has to become instructions how to easily take down the Tor network with practical steps.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can vote to close every question which you find inappropriate. It needs votes from other Tor.SE users to really close it. If there are none, the question will stay open.

Regarding your question I would agree on the first question. It seems too broad for me. However especially you should always comment on the question when you want to close it. This will help the user to create a better question next time or to rephrase the current one.

When it comes to [my questions](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/196/would-distributed-denial-of-service-ddos-attacks-on-the-directory-authorities) I'm obviously against a vote to close. :-)
While the general question is obvious, there is a nuance which might be interesting. From my knowledge DDoSing DAs will not bring the network down immediately. As far as I know existing connections will stay and clients will also use informations from other Tor relays. I was expecting an answer along those lines.

Comment: You may not like "How can one make Tor faster, when willing to to sacrifice anonymity?" for whatever reason. But too broad, really?

Comment: Maybe just rephrasing the question and doing away with the DDoS part would improve it.  There are many reasons why servers may become unavailable.